# PCB thermal simulation with MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, pcb, thermal

I am looking to simulate thermal performance of MOSFETs on a PCB and would like to get recommendations of ways to do it. Some considerations would be

- Multiple MOSFETs are in parallel with control from a single gate driver
- This is without any switching of the MOSFETs and with a steady flow of current.
- I have access to the Cauer model of the MOSFETs being used

The simulation is required to optimize the placement of the MOSFETs. This means the simulation software needs to take into consideration that if a MOSFET carries more current due to the layout and heats up, it will increase its Rds-ON.